# How to print values in a list on separate lines? Must use a for statement.

Tags: python, for-loop, pycharm

I need to use a for statement in order to print each value of a list on separate lines. When using the for statement it prints the entire list on one line. Additionally when trying to print just the values in the list on the same line it appears with double brackets instead of single.

```
Numbers=range(5,25,4)
NumberSequence=[]
NumberSequence.append(Numbers)
print NumberSequence
for elem in NumberSequence:
    print elem
NumberSequence2=[]
Numbers2=range(26,0,-7)
NumberSequence2.append(Numbers2)
print NumberSequence2
for digits in NumberSequence2:
    print digits
```

Comment: Instead of `NumberSequence.append(Numbers)` try `NumberSequence.extend(Numbers)`. Is this a university course? You're suggesting there are restrictions on what you can do but you're using Python 2 which is soon to basically expire.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a university course and the book does not always seem to match up to the version of Python we are using (which is in the program pycharm edu). This worked perfectly though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you made a list and then put it inside of another list. If I understand you correctly, you want to print each individual number on a separate line. This can be done with:

```
Numbers = range(5,24,4)
for elem in Numbers:
    print elem
```

Also, as @roganjosh mentioned, you seem to be using Python 2 which is rather old, slower than Python 3, and it's days of being supported are numbered. I highly recommend you make the switch to python 3 :)